# Print root and children in a tree in python

Tags: python, object

I have a program that creates a tree by nesting the object creation as below. I know its not the correct way but I have to print the values at each level.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children


exTree = Node(1, [
              Node(2, []), Node(3, [
                   Node(4, [
                        Node(5, []), Node(6, [
                             Node(7,[])
              ])])])])
```

I tried accessing the values but couldn't find a way.

The tree is as below -
[image: tree]

And I have to print the values as below:

```
print(treeToString(extree)
>1
>23
>4
>56
>7
```

**UPDATE** -
I am able to achieve the following so far but its not in the correct format required. I have to create one function only.

```
def treeToString(exTree):
    print(exTree.value)
    for child in exTree.children:
        treeToString(child)

treeToString(extree)
```

Output -

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: this is known as level order traversal

Comment: What problems did you encounter accessing the values?  `exTree.value` should give you `1`.  `[node.value for node in exTree.children]` should give you `[2, 3]`.  Right?

Comment: @Samwise Just a few minutes ago I was able to get the first two levels too. But cannot go any deeper. I am trying recursively accessing the values.

Comment: Google "level order traversal", or maybe "breadth first search".  Breadth-first is easier with an iterative loop than with recursion IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a generator to `yield` one level at a time. This is very versatile as it lets you do all kinds of things with the output, not just `print`.

```py
def levels(trees):
    if trees:
        yield tuple([tree.value for tree in trees])
        yield from levels([child for tree in trees for child in tree.children])
```

Example:

```py
>>> list(levels([exTree]))
[(1,), (2, 3), (4,), (5, 6), (7,)]
```

From there, you can print if you like, or write pytests and doctests, or use in other applications.

```py
for v in levels([exTree]):
    print(' '.join(map(str, v)))
```

Output:

```
1
2 3
4
5 6
7
```

(Note: use `''.join(...)` above to suppress the space and match exactly your desired output, but I think it's more explanatory with the space).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it in the following way:

```
def treeToString(extree):
   rep = str(extree.value) + "\n"
   return _treeToStringAux(extree, rep)

def _treeToStringAux(extree, rep):
    for child in extree.children:
        rep+= str(child.value)
    if not (rep[-1] == "\n"):
        rep+="\n"
    for child in extree.children:
        rep = _treeToStringAux(child, rep)
    return rep


print(treeToString(exTree))
```

gives the result.

The part where I check the `\n` is because due to the way I traverse the tree I sometimes get two newlines